# html input not clearing on jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm having an issue with removing classes from a HTML input when that element becomes empty.

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/GgFXs/4/

This happens for a split second, or if you hold the backspace button in the field.
Any time after, the field takes on the 'valid' class - why? and how to fix?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the input event - are you sure that's the event you meant to bind?

Comment: yes, i use 'input' because it fires on all key presses + pastes

Comment: I *think* it's working for me. When I erased all my input, the background turned white again. Is that not the behavior you want?

edit: actually, I take that back - I had put an alert in there and I think that caused a different timing condition - when I removed it the background stayed green. I'll have to look at it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up functionality from the Validation plugin with your own code. You can remove the `valid` className, but the Validation plugin will add it back if it thinks the field is valid.

If you want a blank field to be rejected by the Validation plugin, you'll have to give it `class="required"`. If you want to be monitoring, adding and removing classes manually, you're not really using the Validation plugin as intended IMO.

Comment: this is perfect, thanks for pointing out that the validation plugin reserves the .valid and .invalid class names. I did not realize this. Changing the class names to my_valid and my_invalid and adding the removeClass()'s worked. Final working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/8QvXP/1/ Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is quite convoluted. You occasionally end up with the undesirable situation of having both `.valid` and `.invalid` applied. Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').validate();
    $('input').bind('input', function() {
        if ($(this).val() != '') $(this).addClass('nonEmpty');
        else $(this).removeClass('nonEmpty');

        if ($(this).valid()) $(this).addClass('valid');
        else $(this).removeClass('valid');
    });
});
```

```
.nonEmpty {background: #E4CCCC;}
.nonEmpty.valid {background: #9BCC60;}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works - but can you explain why my logic is 'quite convoluted', and why my method was not working?

Comment: +1, and note that the onInput event is not supported in IE 8 or lower. It works in IE 9. http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php

Comment: @Jordan: Well for one, your code allows an input to be both valid and invalid! It's hard to tell what's the cause of the persisting valid state.

Comment: Oops, Indeed - I forgot to call .removeClass() on the selectors to remove the opposite class. I've made this change on jsfiddle but the valid state persists. If anybody can explain why, please do. @Will Martin: thanks for this.